# Удаление файлов через Cron php

Tags: php, cron

Есть такой скрипт

```
foreach (glob("*.jpg") as $filename) { 
  echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "n"; 
  unlink($filename); 
}
```

он удаляет все jpg файлы в той папке, где лежит сам скрипт. он работает, если его запускать самому через браузер. но через крон он не работает. поставил выполнение каждые 6 часов, и ничего он не удаляет. запускал вручную через крон, тоже 0 результата

в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Что пишет в лог ? скорее всего у крона нет прав на выполнения вашего скрипта

Comment: удаляются файлы в текущем каталоге, а не «там, где находится скрипт». меняйте текущий каталог либо внутри скрипта, либо «снаружи», перед его вызовом.

Comment: это как понять в текущем каталоге? 
команда в кроне /usr/bin/php ~/site.ru/public_html/bd/delete.php

Comment: При чем здесь крон? По хорошему вам нужно переписать вопрос и текст. Если при запуске скрипта из консоли, удаление не работает, понятное дело что и по крону оно работать не будет.

Comment: хорошо, по другому тогда, какой скрипт удалит из папки все jpg файлы с помощью крона?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Удалить файлы в папке cron php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/675695/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-cron-php)

Comment: [текущий каталог](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3) — это свойство запущенного процесса. какой именно каталог будет текущим при запуске процесса программой cron, насколько мне известно, нигде не специфицировано, но обычно это домашний каталог пользователя, от имени которого выполняется cron-задание. // меняется текущий каталог в оболочке командой `cd`, в php — функцией `chdir()`

Answer (score 1):

Используйте константу `__DIR__` в пути. Либо перед выполнением в кроне делать `cd /directory/for/script/ && php script.php`

```
foreach (glob(__DIR__"/*.jpg") as $filename) { 
  echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "n"; 
  unlink($filename); 
}
```