# Удалить файлы в папке cron php

Tags: php, cron

Нужно каждые 6 часов чистить заданную папку от файлов. Нигде не могу найти решение. До этого с кроном не работал

Comment: вообще классикой для пхп является вариант с проверкой каждый раз "а не пора ли было почистить". Если пора - то чистим. Если ресурс посещаем это работате.

Comment: возможный дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/675407/178576

Comment: «без cron-а» вы же знаете, как удалить файлы? `rm /путь/к/каталогу/*`. «с cron-ом» — абсолютно точно так же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

команда оболочки для удаления файлов в каталоге (если в этом каталоге нет вложенных каталогов):

```
rm /путь/к/каталогу/*
```

---

вот эту команду и надо выполнять, указав её периодичность. т.е., для «раз в шесть часов» строчка в файле `crontab` должна выглядеть примерно так:

```
0 */6 * * * rm /путь/к/каталогу/*
```

т.е., в `0` минут каждые шесть часов (второе поле — `*/6`) каждый день месяца (третье поле — `*`) каждый месяц (четвёртое поле — `*`) независимо от дня недели (пятое поле — `*`) выполнять команду `rm ...` (последнее, шестое поле).

Comment: как правильно указать путь к каталогу? как я в браузере ввожу, или как на хостинге расположено? например вот такой путь отображается, когда в кроне выбираю папку мастером заданий

/usr/bin/php ~/site.ru/public_html/bd

как будет правильно в таком случае указать?

Comment: путь к файлу/каталогу — он и в африке путь: `~/site.ru/public_html/bd`. только не забудьте про резервную копию до начала экспериментов.

Answer (score 0):

```
find $LOCATION -name $REQUIRED_FILES -type f -mmin +360 -delete
```

где `+360` кол-во минут (360 минут == 6 часов)

Comment: Во-первых, объясните, как это работает и что всё это значит, во-вторых, думаю, имелось в виду не удаление файлов старее/новее 6 часов, а удаление вообще всех каждые 6 часов, в-третьих, тут ни слова про крон, как эту команду регулярно запускать-то?

Answer (score 0):

```
find /путь к каталогу/ -type f -mmin +360 -delete
```

скрипт удаления файлов старше 360 минут
регулярный запуск настроек во время создания крона задаёте, если вы в ispmgr